# Flutter plugin instance with parameters

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to make a plugin for authentication. It will act like a "wrapper" (but with additional functionality for each plugin) for different already existing packages for different platforms.

By the additional functionality I mean

- Web implementation already has state management
- Android implementation is AppAuth, so here I need to add my own state management

I am trying to use the `PlatformInterface` way, but I cannot find any guide how to make it instantiable with constructor params.

Let's say I have this code:

```dart
abstract class KeycloakAuth extends PlatformInterface {
  KeycloakAuth()
    : super(token: _token);

  static final Object _token = Object();

  static late KeycloakAuth _instance = KeycloakAuth._setPlatform();
  static KeycloakAuth get instance => _instance;

  static set platform(KeycloakAuth instance) {
    PlatformInterface.verifyToken(instance, _token);
    _instance = instance;
  }

  factory KeycloakAuth._setPlatform() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return KeycloakAuthAppAuth();
    } else {
      throw UnimplementedError('The current platform ${Platform.operatingSystem} is not supported.');
    }
  }
}
```

This would work, but in my app I would like to do this:

```dart
final _keycloakAuth = KeycloakAuth(keycloakUrl: 'xxx', clientId: 'yyy');
```

If I simply tried to add params like this:

```dart
abstract class KeycloakAuth extends PlatformInterface {
  final String keycloakUrl;
  final String clientId;

  KeycloakAuth({
    required this.keycloakUrl,
    required this.clientId,
  })
    : super(token: _token);
...
```

I wouldn't be able to pass them inside the `_setPlatform()` method since this is static method.

Also `KeycloakAuthAppAuth` extends `KeycloakAuth`, so I would need to pass those parameters back and forth, like instantiate `KeycloakAuth`, this instantiates `KeycloakAuthAppAuth` which needs to pass those parameters back via `super()`...

Any tips for this?

I know I can make a method `initialize({String keycloakUrl, String clientId})` with my parameters, but I would still like to know if it's possible to make it using the constructor.